# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9]

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

I created `cordova app` in my folder.

(`cordova create MyApp`)

(`cordova platform add android`)

I moved `google-services.json` to `MyApp/platforms/android/app/`.

But when I tried to run:

(`cordova run android`)

I got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I tried change `implementation()` to `compile()`, but it reported the method compile() is missing to.

In `dependencies` the version of Gradle is 3.3.0.

In `gradle-wrapper.properties` the version of `distributionUrl` is 4.10.3.

In `gradle -v` in my terminal the version is 5.4.1.

`cordova plugins` => only `cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"`

Answer (score 0):

if possible, share your `build.gradle` or `config.xml` file.

OR

You can try by checking your `build.gradle` file in folder `MyApp/platforms/android/app/`.
open the `build.gradle` file  and find dependencies tag like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
}
```

if `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'` is missing then add this dependencies and re-run the command `cordova run android`